# tensorflow - Can I get some useful information from these tensorflow diagrams to correct my model?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I'm suffering some problems in my model. The model seems not learning because the accuracy remains the same value.

I've been trying to solve this training problem for several days and I haven't figure out what's wrong with my model, so I try to take advantage of `tensorboard`.

The result shown in the tensorboard:

### **NOTE**: Only fc6, fc7, fc8 layers are to be trained, since the previous conv layers are pretrained.

**graph**

[image: graph]

---

**accuracy**
[image]

---

**cross_entropy**
[image]

---

**distribution of fc6 layer**
[image]

---

**histogram of three trained fc layers**
[image]
[image]

**Can I know from the `graph` diagram that the backprop is conducted properly? Or the backprop is to be done by tensorflow and won't be presented here?**

**From the `histogram`, I suppose the parameters are, indeed, trained in the first epoch, but I don't know why it seems not to be trained in the following epochs.**

**I wonder how I can interpret the diagrams and extract useful information so that I can get to know where might be the incorrect part of my code. (I've searched how to interpret `tensorboard` diagrams and I can't get any inspiration on how can I interpret my own.)**

I can give the code if it's needed, but it's a bit long so I'm not presenting it now.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Can you share your code?

Comment: Here, it seems that you are not learning anything. Weights are initialized only and they do not change over time. Can you provide more information? what optimization algorithm are you using? And yes, code will be helpful.